# Gneric type in Java about what is the actual return type?

Tags: java, generics

Here is a snippet code of generic class in Java

```
public class PairTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LocalDate[] birthdays = {....}    // initialize birthdays array
        Pair<LocalDate> mm = ArrayAlg.minmax(birthdays); // THIS LINE !
    }
}

public ArrayAlg{
    public static < T extends Comparable> Pair<T> minmax(T[] a){
        T min = a[0];
        T max = a[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            if(min.compareTo(a[i] > 0) min = a[i];
            if(max.compareTo(a[i] < 0) max = a[i];
        }
        return new Pair<>(min,max);
    }
}
```

my question is, the line commented as `THIS LINE !` does tell what generic type for static method minmax, so I should interpret this line as `Pair<LocalDate> mm = ArrayAlg.<LocalDate>minmax(birthdays);`.

Or the generic method type is based on the parameter type I pass into which is 'a', for example, if `ArrayAlg.minmax(SubOfLocalDate[] a)`, it returns `new Pair<SubOfLocalDate> (min, max)` for that static method.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes and yes.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is on what basis the compiler infered the type argument of the generic method, then yes it's based on the declared type of the method argument `birthdays` which is of type `LocalDate[]`. The type parameter `T` is therefore bound to `LocalDate` (which implements `Comparable` so it matches the upper bound of `T`).

Note that in this case the compiler does not need to check the declared type of the assigned variable `mm` to determine the bound type argument. If the assigned variable is declared with another type, i.e. if `mm` were of type `Pair<SomeOtherType>`, the compiler would generate an error.

Comment: "Note that the compiler does not need to check the declared type of the assigned variable mm to determine the bound type argument." Sometimes it does; just not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

At runtime

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Pair<T> minmax(T[] a) {
```

becomes with type erasure

```
public static Pair<Comparable> minmax(Comparable[] a) {
```

and

```
Pair<LocalDate> mm = ArrayAlg.minmax(birthdays);
```

is actually just

```
Pair mm = ArrayAlg.minmax(birthdays);
```

Comment: Where the compiler adds cast on these code ?? Compiler add convert all generic to RAW type and automatically add cast, right ?